# "Developer Options" is turned off and can't be changed - Android Galaxy s6

Tags: android, android-studio, galaxy

My Galaxy s6 gone crazy - suddenly "Developer options" is turned off and gray out, With only one button that say that is off and can't change his status to "on". when clicking on it nothing happens.

[image: Developer Options turned off and can't be changed]

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found the problem:
I had an Application installed on my device that blocked Developer Mode. This Application (Made by VMware) has some security that probably blocking Developer Mode as you can see in the picture. After I deleted it - it opened again.

Yuval

Comment: Hello, you can accept your own answer. This will keep the question from popping up among unanswered questions. Thanks.